# How to reproduce case class behaviour with apply/unapply methods?

Tags: scala, case-class

I tried to replace case class with mundane class and companion object and suddenly get type error.

Code that compiles fine (synthetic example):

```
trait Elem[A,B] {
  def ::[C](other : Elem[C,A]) : Elem[C,B] = other match {
    case Chain(head, tail) => Chain(head, tail :: this)
    case simple => Chain(simple, this)
  }
}
class Simple[A,B] extends Elem[A,B]
final case class Chain[A,B,C](head : Elem[A,B], tail : Elem[B,C]) extends Elem[A,C]
```

Change the last definition with:

```
final class Chain[A,B,C](val head : Elem[A,B], val tail : Elem[B,C]) extends Elem[A,C]
object Chain {
  def unapply[A,B,C](src : Chain[A,B,C]) : Option[(Elem[A,B], Elem[B,C])] =
    Some( (src.head, src.tail) )
  def apply[A,B,C](head : Elem[A,B], tail : Elem[B,C]) : Chain[A,B,C] =
    new Chain(head, tail)
}
```

But that seemingly equivalent code make compiler emit errors:

```
CaseMystery.scala:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : test.casemystery.Fail.Elem[A,B] where type B, type A >: C <: C
 required: test.casemystery.Fail.Elem[A,Any] where type A >: C <: C
Note: B <: Any, but trait Elem is invariant in type B.
You may wish to define B as +B instead. (SLS 4.5)
      case Chain(head, tail) => Chain(head, tail :: this)
                                  ^
CaseMystery.scala:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : test.casemystery.Fail.Elem[B(in method ::),B(in trait Elem)] where type B(in method ::)
 required: test.casemystery.Fail.Elem[Any,B(in trait Elem)]
Note: B <: Any, but trait Elem is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
      case Chain(head, tail) => Chain(head, tail :: this)
                                             ^
two errors found
```

What is the difference between implicitly created method with the case statement and explicitly written methods for mundane class?

Comment: Could you comment on the version of Scala you're running? and the line of code at `CaseMystery.scala:17`? When I copy and paste your code into a worksheet and add `new Simple[Int, String] :: new Simple[String, Int] :: new Simple[Int, Double] :: new Simple[Double, String]` it all compiles and runs fine.

Comment: Both scala compiler 2.11.7 and 2.11.8. I created two examples in the single file. One with case class definition (module Ok compiles fine), in the second (module Fail) I copied all but the last line and replace case module with mundane class, the compiler shows error. Line is shown: `case Chain(head, tail) => Chain(head, tail :: this)`

Comment: @AngeloGenovese probably you encountered no erros, because the REPL session keeps old definition of the `trait Elem`. If you starts empty session and puts here only mundane class definition without case modifier it should fail

Comment: Actually, I hadn't defined the case class at all, and intellij's worksheets don't have the same behaviour as the repl. It seems that this code works in 2.10 though, that was the scala version I happened to have open when I noticed your question.

Comment: http://ix.io/1fii/scala - full REPL output

Answer (score 3):

This answer ended up being longer than I expected. If you just want the guts of what is happening with type inference, skip to the end. Otherwise, you get led through the steps of getting to the answer.

#### The problem is in the `case`, but not the one in `case class`

In this case, as much as I hate to admit it, case classes really are magic. In particular, they get special treatment at the type checker level (I think we can agree that your code would work if it got past that phase - you might even be able to throw enough casts at it to make that work).

The problem is, surprisingly enough, not in the class `Chain` itself, but in the places it is used, specifically in the pattern matching part. For example, consider the case class

```
case class Clazz(field: Int)
```

Then, you expect the following to be equivalent:

```
Clazz(3) match { case Clazz(i) => i }
// vs
val v = Clazz.unapply(Clazz(3))
if (v.isDefined) v.get else throw new Exception("No match")
```

But, Scala wants to be more clever and optimize this. In particular, this `unapply` method pretty can pretty much never fail (let's ignore `null` for now) and is probably used a lot, so Scala wants to avoid it altogether and just extract the fields as it usually would get any member of an object. As my compiler professor is fond of saying, "compilers are the art of cheating without getting caught".

Yet here there is a difference in the type-checker. The problem is in

```
def ::[Z, X](other : Elem[Z, X]) : Elem[Z, Y] = other match {
  case Chain(head, tail) => Chain(head, tail :: this)
  case simple => Chain(simple, this)
}
```

If you compile with `-Xprint:typer` you'll see what the type checker sees. The case class version has

```
def ::[C](other: Elem[C,A]): Elem[C,B] = other match {
  case (head: Elem[C,Any], tail: Elem[Any,A])Chain[C,Any,A]((head @ _), (tail @ _)) => Chain.apply[C, Any, B](head, {
    <synthetic> <artifact> val x$1: Elem[Any,A] = tail;
    this.::[Any](x$1)
  })
  case (simple @ _) => Chain.apply[C, A, B](simple, this)
}
```

While the regular class has

```
def ::[C](other: Elem[C,A]): Elem[C,B] = other match {
  case Chain.unapply[A, B, C](<unapply-selector>) <unapply> ((head @ _), (tail @ _)) => Chain.apply[A, Any, B](<head: error>, {
    <synthetic> <artifact> val x$1: Elem[_, _ >: A <: A] = tail;
    this.::[B](x$1)
  })
  case (simple @ _) => Chain.apply[C, A, B](simple, this)
}
```

So the type checker actually gets a different (special) case construct.

#### So what does the `match` get translated to?

Just for fun, we can check what happens at the next phase `-Xprint:patmat` which expands out patterns (although here the fact that these are no longer really valid Scala programs really becomes painful). First, the case class has

```
def ::[C](other: Elem[C,A]): Elem[C,B] = {
  case <synthetic> val x1: Elem[C,A] = other;
  case5(){
    if (x1.isInstanceOf[Chain[C,Any,A]])
      {
        <synthetic> val x2: Chain[C,Any,A] = (x1.asInstanceOf[Chain[C,Any,A]]: Chain[C,Any,A]);
        {
          val head: Elem[C,Any] = x2.head;
          val tail: Elem[Any,A] = x2.tail;
          matchEnd4(Chain.apply[C, Any, B](head, {
            <synthetic> <artifact> val x$1: Elem[Any,A] = tail;
            this.::[Any](x$1)
          }))
        }
      }
    else
      case6()
  };
  case6(){
    matchEnd4(Chain.apply[C, A, B](x1, this))
  };
  matchEnd4(x: Elem[C,B]){
    x
  }
}
```

Although a lot of stuff is confusing here, notice that we *never use the `unapply` method*! For the non-case class version, I'll use the working code from user1303559:

```
def ::[Z, XX >: X](other: Elem[Z,XX]): Elem[Z,Y] = {
  case <synthetic> val x1: Elem[Z,XX] = other;
  case6(){
    if (x1.isInstanceOf[Chain[A,B,C]])
      {
        <synthetic> val x2: Chain[A,B,C] = (x1.asInstanceOf[Chain[A,B,C]]: Chain[A,B,C]);
        {
          <synthetic> val o8: Option[(Elem[A,B], Elem[B,C])] = Chain.unapply[A, B, C](x2);
          if (o8.isEmpty.unary_!)
            {
              val head: Elem[Z,Any] = o8.get._1;
              val tail: Elem[Any,XX] = o8.get._2;
              matchEnd5(Chain.apply[Z, Any, Y](head, {
                <synthetic> <artifact> val x$1: Elem[Any,XX] = tail;
                this.::[Any, XX](x$1)
              }))
            }
          else
            case7()
        }
      }
    else
      case7()
  };
  case7(){
    matchEnd5(Chain.apply[Z, XX, Y](x1, this))
  };
  matchEnd5(x: Elem[Z,Y]){
    x
  }
}
```

And here, sure enough, the `unapply` method makes an appearance.

#### It isn't actually cheating (for the Pros)

Of course, Scala doesn't actually cheat - this behavior is all in the specification. In particular, we see that [constructor patterns](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#constructor-patterns) from which case classes benefit are kind of special, since, amongst other things, they are [irrefutable](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#irrefutable-patterns) (related to what I was saying above about Scala not wanting to use the `unapply` method since it "knows" it is just extracting the fields).

The part that really interests us though is [8.3.2 Type parameter inference for constructor patterns](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#type-parameter-inference-for-constructor-patterns). The difference between the regular class and the case class is that `Chain` pattern is a "constructor pattern" when `Chain` is a case class, and just a regular pattern otherwise. The constructor pattern

```
other match {
  case Chain(head, tail) => Chain(head, tail :: this)
  case simple => Chain(simple, this)
}
```

ends up getting typed as though it were

```
other match {
  case _: Chain[a1,a2,a3] => ...
}
```

Then, based on the fact that `other: Elem[C,A]` from the argument types and the fact that `Chain[a1,a2,a3] extends Elem[a1,a3]`, we get that `a1` is `C`, `a3` is `A` and `a2` can by anything, so is `Any`. Hence why the types in the output of `-Xprint:typer` for the case class has an `Chain[C,Any,A]` in it. This does type check.

However, constructor patterns are specific to case classes, so no - there is no way to imitate the case class behavior here.

> A constructor pattern is of the form `c(p1,…,pn)` where `n≥0`. It
>   consists of a stable identifier `c`, followed by element patterns
>   `p1,…,pn`. The constructor `c` is a simple or qualified name which
>   denotes a `case class`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `other` is `Elem[C, A]`, but after you had tried to match it as `Chain(head, tail)` it actually matched to `Chain[C, some inner B, A](head: Elem[C, inner B], tail: Elem[inner B, A])`. After that you create `Chain[C, inner B <: Any, A](head: Elem[C, inner B], (tail :: this): Elem[inner B, B])`

But result type must be `Elem[C, B]`, or `Chain[C, Any, B]`. So compiler trying to cast  `inner B` to `Any`. But beacause `inner B` is **invariant** - you must have exactly `Any`.

This is actually better rewrite as follows:

```
trait Elem[X, Y] {
  def ::[Z, X](other : Elem[Z, X]) : Elem[Z, Y] = other match {
    case Chain(head, tail) => Chain(head, tail :: this)
    case simple => Chain(simple, this)
  }
}

final class Chain[A, B, C](val head : Elem[A, B], val tail : Elem[B, C]) extends Elem[A, C]

object Chain {
  def unapply[A,B,C](src : Chain[A,B,C]) : Option[(Elem[A,B], Elem[B,C])] =
    Some( (src.head, src.tail) )
  def apply[A,B,C](head : Elem[A,B], tail : Elem[B,C]) : Chain[A,B,C] =
    new Chain(head, tail)
}
```

After this error message becoming much more informative and it is obviously how to repair this.

However I don't know why that works for case classes. Sorry.

Working example is:

```
trait Elem[+X, +Y] {
  def ::[Z, XX >: X](other : Elem[Z, XX]) : Elem[Z, Y] = other match {
    case Chain(head, tail) => Chain(head, tail :: this)
    case simple => Chain(simple, this)
  }
}

final class Chain[A, B, C](val head : Elem[A, B], val tail : Elem[B, C]) extends Elem[A, C]

object Chain {
  def unapply[A,B,C](src : Chain[A,B,C]) : Option[(Elem[A,B], Elem[B,C])] =
    Some( (src.head, src.tail) )
  def apply[A,B,C](head : Elem[A,B], tail : Elem[B,C]) : Chain[A,B,C] =
    new Chain(head, tail)
}
```

**EDITED:**

Eventually I found that:

```
case class A[T](a: T)
List(A(1), A("a")).collect { case A(x) => A(x) }
// res0: List[A[_ >: String with Int]] = List(A(1), A(a))

class B[T](val b: T)
object B {
  def unapply[T](b: B[T]): Option[T] = Option(b.b)
}
List(new B(1), new B("b")).collect { case B(x) => new B(x) }
// res1: List[B[Any]] = List(B@1ee4afee, B@22eaba0c)
```

Obvious that it is compiler feature. So I think no way there to reproduce the full case class behavior.

Comment: Well, it is pretty obvious and expected, that compiler lost types somewhere. I'm more interested how case class managed to keep them

Comment: I think that because case classes are final by definition and compiler allows something exclusive for them. May be that compiler bug, since such behaviour breaks invariance. I am trying to solve this puzzle late.

Comment: Case classes are not final by definition.

Comment: Sorry. I mean they are can not inherited by other case classes. They least upper bound are not computes like for regular classes.